# Unsupervised learning python: x,y,z movement clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset composed of 3000 observations. For each observation, I have 4 features: time, position on the x-axis, position on the y-axis, position on the z-axis.
The data are related to the acceleration of a vehicle.
Basically the vehicle can be on three states: accelerating, decelerating and remain at the same velocity. The states are repeated in the dataset (the vehicle accelerates, decelerates, stops and then repeats the sequence).

I would like to cluster my dataset in these categories and then add a new column to the dataset with the result of the cluster.

I tried to apply KMeans (after standardizing the data) but I obtain three clusters of the same dimension (to me this is strange since acceleration and deceleration last more than the stops) that do not repeat themselves. Basically, it is as if the KMeans just splits the dataset into equal parts without considering the characteristics of the dataset.

Maybe I should use a different algorithm? Should I approach the problem from a different perspective?

The sample of the dataset:
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA0GY.png)

I tried to extract the values of the velocity and of the acceleration. The problem now is that I have problems in standardizing the dataset

```
ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: You should work on feature extraction.  Can you estimate velocity and acceleration from the raw data?  If so, and you know a priori that these are the important properties you want, then you should do so.

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset

Comment: I posted a sample of the dataset